# How to Modify Base Class to Dynamically Instantiate Appropriate Subclass Without Causing Recursion?

Tags: python-3.x, django, recursion, design-patterns

I am refactoring a Python class structure where I previously instantiated subclasses directly, but now I want to shift to a design where I only call a base generator class, and this base class internally decides and returns the appropriate subclass instance. However, I'm encountering a recursion problem with this new approach. My code is:

```
class BaseGenerator:
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls is BaseGenerator:
            subclass = cls._determine_subclass(*args, **kwargs)
            return subclass(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return super().__new__(cls)

    @staticmethod
    def _determine_subclass(*args, **kwargs):
        # Logic to determine the appropriate subclass
        # ...

class ChildGenerator1(BaseGenerator):
    pass

class ChildGenerator2(BaseGenerator):
    pass

class ChildGenerator3(BaseGenerator):
    pass
```

Initially, I had a structure with one base generator class (BaseGenerator) and several subclasses (ChildGenerator1, ChildGenerator2, ChildGenerator3). I used to instantiate these subclasses directly like this:

```
generator = ChildGenerator1(...)
```

Now, I want to only use the **BaseGenerator** to decide and instantiate the correct subclass. I tried implementing this logic in the **new** method of BaseGenerator, but this leads to a recursion issue
now I'm calling the generator like this:

```
generator = BaseGenerator(...)
```

The problem is that when **BaseGenerator** redirects to a subclass, it somehow causes a recursion issue. How can I modify this approach to dynamically instantiate the correct subclass from **BaseGenerator** without causing recursion?

Any suggestions or insights on how to correctly implement this pattern would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is withholding you from using a simple function and just instantiating the base class if the requirements are not met?

Comment: The main gain here is that instead of the factory function being an ordinary function, it is an actual class, to which `isinstance(my_object, DynamicBase)` will return True. it is a small feature, but a nice to have. Other than that, a factory function would work equally well.

Answer (score 0):

In the code as you've written, you simply instantiate a class from its own `__new__` method (even if the subclasses had their own `__new__`, they'd eventyally have to call `super().__new__`, and you would fall in recursion again.

What you have to do, is, knowing that what actually creates the instance is `object.__new__`, (called as `super().__new__` from your baseclass), to pass the final class into *that* call:

One further thing to take into consideration in this design, is that Python only calls `__init__` in an instance if `__new__` returns an instance of its own class - if it returns any other thing, including a subclass of the class where `__new__` is, `__init__` has to be called manually.

So, simplifying your snippet a bit further, this is the idea:

```
class Base:
    def __new__(cls):
        final_cls = SubClass1 # omitting _determine_subclass stub
        instance = super().__new__(final_cls)
        instance.__init__()
        return instance
        
    def __init__(self):
        print("At Base init")


class SubClass1(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        print("At subclass init")
        super().__init__()

b = Base()
```

Actually, I've used this pattern myself, more than once - my favorite use being these classes that act both as tokens when parsing an expression and AST nodes once they are parsed:

https://github.com/turicas/rows/blob/c0b24ce41e2ef08324bd3ee04ffc9800b6f950f3/rows/utils/query.py#L55

```
    ...

    def __new__(cls, value=_sentinel):
        """Specialized __new__ acts as a factory for whatever subclass best matches
        what is given as "value". Inheritance of subclasses, though, work as usual:
        it is just class instantiation for all subclasses that is centralized here.

        (I wonder if there is a "gang of four name" for this)
        """
        ...
```